# Find the line between two planes (not using vector product).

Tags: linear-algebra

I stumbled on to this example in my math book, this is presented before the vector product is introduced.

**lets say we have an equation system like this:**

$$\left( \begin{array}{3} x + 2y -3z = 3 \\ a^2x + (2a+4)y - (3a+6) = 3a +6 \\ x+ay-3z= 5-a \end{array}\right )$$

Now if you calculate the determinant you will see that the system above have a solution if:

$ a \neq -1$ and $a \neq 2$

**If you solve for values other than those you will see that the point $(0, -1, \frac{-5}{3})$ belongs to the three planes, independent of $a$.**

**So if we take the case of $a=-1$ then the planes:**

$P_1 = x + 2y -3z = 3$ and $P_2 = a^2x + (2a+4)y - (3a+6) = 3a +6$ will be identical.

We are then left with the equation system like this:

$$\left( \begin{array}{3} x + 2y -3z = 3 \\ x -y-3z= 6 \end{array}\right )$$

**where the line $l : (x,y,z) = (5,-1,0) + t(3,0,1)$ is the solution.**

***Now my question to you is how can they know that the line above is the solution?***

My approach would be to find another point that satisfies the equation system and then calculate the line vector and use the $(0, -1, \frac{-5}{3})$ as the the first reference point, but how can I find the second point?

Thank you!

Comment: Obviously you could look at the equation system $\left( \begin{array}{3} x + 2y -3z = 3 \\ x -y-3z= 6 \end{array}\right )$ and guess a solution, like $(5,-1,0)$ from there you could find a linear combination $(5,-1,0) + t(x,y,z)$ that would produce the point $(0, -1, \frac{-5}{3})$. But there should be a method that does not rely on guessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must just get a generalized solution for \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&-3&| &3 \\ 1&-1&-3&|&6 \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation}After row reduction I get \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&-3&| &3 \\ 0&-1&0&|&1 \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation} So if we let $z=t$ we get $y=-1$ and $x=5+3t$, and therefore we have the general solution $(x,y,z)=(5+3t,-1,t)=(5,-1,0)+t(3,0,1)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Much appreciated!